# Unknown: send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe | MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Запускаю файл cron'a, который делает 1 запрос к базе данных, а потом длительное время(около минуты) выполняет рассылку. В итоге вылезла эта ошибка. Что она означает? Истечение времени соединения с сервером mysql?

Comment: Пытался даже закрыть соединение pdo, присвовив переменной $pdo = null, но все равно ошибка вылазит, хоть и закрываю соединение сразу после получения данных.

Comment: Дело не в коде, разбивать там нечего, просто сервис принимает не так быстро сообщения рассылки. Лимит для скрипта был 5 минут, выполнялся около минуты, не в этом дело) Просто бд выдает ошибку, а как ее убрать не пойму, хоть она и не мешает.